# cakephp file notempty validation - bug?

Tags: cakephp

How to get an input type file to validate for notempty in cake?

When you submit the form without adding a file the validation says it is empty even though $this->request->data shows the file.

// Model/Product.php

```
class Product extends AppModel {
  public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),
 );

}
```

// Controller/ProductController.php

```
 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Product->create();
        if ($this->Product->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your product has been saved.');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your product.');
            debug($this->request->data);
            debug($this->Product->validationErrors);
        }
    }
}
```

// View/Products/add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can actually use notEmpty on the -somewhat special- file field. The file field is handled differently than any other input field, as it returns the superglobal $_FILES as a result. As such, you should check it a little bit differently. There is actually quite a good example in the [CakePHP Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#validating-uploads).

Now this is for actually uploaded files, but you can easily change it by checking if the `name` key is not empty and actually set. Something like this as a custom validation rule in your Model should do the trick:

```
public function fileSelected($file) {
    return (is_array($file) && array_key_exists('name', $file) && !empty($file['name']));
}
```

And then just set this as validation rule for your file field:

```
public $validate = array(
   'name' => array(
       'rule' => 'fileSelected'
   ),
);
```